# Jacoco report showing deleted java class for test coverage

Tags: java, junit, jacoco, intellij-15

I have simply deleted the java class file which was of no use.After building the package in intellij, Jacoco test report showing deleted java class as well. For reference, I have attached sceenshot.

Is there any reference exists even after deleting java class file in intellij. How can I completely resolve this issue?
[image]

Comment: have you deleted both `*.java` and `*.class` files? have you checked (file system) that **both** file were deleted? (deleting the `*.class` file but building the package will create it again, from `*.java`; but I don't know Jacoco, not sure what is cached)

Answer (score 3):

Run the `clean` command for whatever build tool you are using (ant, maven, gradle).

If you only run the `jacocoTestReport` occasionally, you might want to add a dependency on `clean` for it, to ensure it always happens before generating the report.

I noticed this same problem when I changed a package name on a class and the old package was still in the report.

What is happening is the report that is created is simply a bunch of files that follow the naming and package convention of the files in your project.  So files from a previous run of `jacocoTestReport` are still sitting in that report folder, even though you have deleted the java file, and rerun `jacocoTestReport`.  If you look in the folder, you will find the timestamp is older on the report file for the deleted class than the others around it.  It just needs the `clean` so that your next run will only contain files related to the current report.

I assume its possible to change where `jacocoTestReport` will write its report files and if you choose somewhere other than the build directory, you would need to update your `clean` task to clean up that area too.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me today. It was due to:

- checking out to a git branch in which a maven module has been deleted
- the corresponding folder was still here, but it was ignored by git since it only contained ignored files (e.g. `.class` files inside `target/`)
- `mvn clean` did not clean those files, since the corresponding module was removed from `pom.xml`
- Jacoco still found the old compiled classes because it looks for `**/classes` and `**/**.exec`, and it doesn't care about `.gitignore` or `pom.xml`.

After removing remove the old files, the coverage reported by Jacoco changed.

I used `git clean -f -d --dry-run` to look for old folders, and removed them with `git clean -f -d`. Please be careful with this command!